# delegate parents events of this in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In my plugin I create items dynamically and delegating the events on these items.
My problem is to delegate the events that are outside (parent) of my object "this" like header so
you can use the plugin on multiple tables on the same page.

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {
            //var $this = $(this);
            //var that = this;

            /* RENDER DYNAMICALLY "THIS" HEADER */
            var hd = "<div class=\"header\"><button type=\"button\" id=\"clickMe\">Click Me</button></div>";
            $(hd).insertBefore(this);

            /* RENDER DYNAMICALLY "THIS" TD */
            var rows = "<tr><td>1</td><td>200</td><td>Foo</td></tr>";
            $(this).find('tbody').html(rows);

            /* DELEGATE "THIS" TD ELEMENT*/
            $(this).on('click', 'td', function() {
                //do something
            });

            /* DELEGATE PARENTS "THIS" ELEMENT */
            // problem if using plugin for more tables in the same page,
            // because header might belong to multiple tables
            $('.header').on('click', '#clickMe', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                //do something
            });

        });
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);


$(#tbl).myPlugin();
```

html

```
<table id="tbl" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

How can I delegate only events that belong to or are parents of my this object?
Thank you

Comment: Important Note: Your plugin code and the "answer" below will not work for multiple instances as duplicate IDs are invalid! Browsers can only see the first occurrence of `#clickMe` in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your trouble this might help:

```js
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {
            //var $this = $(this);
            var that = this;

            /* RENDER DYNAMICALLY "THIS" HEADER */
            var hd = "<div class=\"header\"><button type=\"button\" id=\"clickMe\">Click Me</div>";
            $(hd).insertBefore(this);

            /* RENDER DYNAMICALLY "THIS" TD */
            var rows = "<tr><td>1</td><td>200</td><td>Foo</td></tr>";
            $(this).find('tbody').html(rows);

            /* DELEGATE "THIS" TD ELEMENT*/
            $(this).on('click', 'td', function() {
                //do something
//                alert($(this).closest('table').attr('id')); 
            });

            /* DELEGATE PARENTS "THIS" ELEMENT */
          // no problem more: you are added button BEFORE table, so get the prev element with class .header
            $(this).prev('.header').on('click', '#clickMe', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                alert('clicked button for ' + $(that).attr('id') + ' table.'); //get table in button
            });

        });
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);


$('.table').myPlugin();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<table id="tbl2" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<table id="tbl3" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: BTW,Try to avoid using the same IDs in HTML (like #clickMe), better use dummy classes instead or data attributes.

Comment: Important Note: Your answer will not work for multiple instances as duplicate IDs are invalid! Browsers can only see the first occurrence of `#clickMe` in the page.

Comment: Actually not, because jquery selector is searching in container with class .header, where #clickMe is the first and only.

Comment: Anyway I edited and used the class selector. Thank you